# Can't find php.ini on mac VVV setup

Tags: php, wordpress, virtualbox, vvv-wordpress

I've just started using VVV with virtualbox. I'm trying to run npm build on the woocoomerce development plugin but it's failing with `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)`

This is expected as mentioned on their github page, the solution is to increase the `memory_limit` but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to find the right file.

So if I take a look at the phpinfo, it tells me that the Loaded Configuration File is `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` but this file doesn't exist. The php directory does not exist inside of my /etc folder.

Am I missing something? Can't seem to solve this, I've edited a few other files and reloaded vagrant, but no luck. Would appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking at the `/etc` folder inside the virtual machine, or on your laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Running `php --ini` will show the path of the configuration file.

Do remember that this should be run inside the Virtualbox container.

> cd project && vagrant ssh

```
$ php --ini
```

For me, it's

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

then adopt you changes and restart with

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: The OP already checked `phpinfo` to get the location of the file, but is saying the file doesn't exist at that location.

Comment: @Cully The OP has most likely looked outside the vagrant vb container.

Comment: thanks @Cully yeah so I was looking in the virtual box, but I needed to ssh into the vagrant container.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I glared over your 'vagrant ssh' comment. But that is what was needed. If you edit the answer to explain logging in to vagrant with ssh, I'll be happy to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

In case any other Vagrant newbs find themselves in a this situation. The memory limit obviously needs to be changed on the vagrant container. Here is the information from the [Vagrant documentation](https://varyingvagrantvagrants.org/docs/en-US/installation/) on how to access with SSH.

SSH
You can SSH into the VM via the vagrant user with the command vagrant ssh. Running vagrant ssh-config will dump out an SSH config you can use to SSH directly into that VM without use of the vagrant command.

Otherwise it is enough to run this command:

`ssh vagrant@vvv.test`

`host = vvv.test`
`username = vagrant`
`password = vagrant`

Also be sure to restart the server as suggest by PatricNox, but for me it was `sudo service nginx restart` not apache2.